# Artifactory for deployment verification

Tags: artifactory

We are currently using SVN scripting to verify what is deployed production matches the last release deployed  and checked into SVN. How can I achieve the same using artifactory?

Answer (score 0):

Artifactory has in-build feature of promoting the artifacts to every stage. You can use this feature to move/promote the artifacts on higher env so that there is a single source of truth i.e artifactory